# Knowing the state of the keyboard in a VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, vscode-extensions, modifier-key

I want to read the state of the keyboard in a VS Code extension and be able to run action A or B depending on whether a modifier key like Shift or Option/Alt is currently pressed.

Is there a way I can read the keyboard? I seem to find no information on this on the [API reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api).

Comment: Is your command(s) triggered from a menu or a keybinding?  If from a menu see the discuusion about using `alt/shift` in the command contribution at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus

Comment: @Mark Actually, from a button atop the editor. Would something similar work?

Comment: How are contributing the button?  Not to a menu I assume?

Comment: @Mark It's contributed to the `commandPalette`.

Answer (score 1):

If your need is for `commands` that your extension contributes, then unfortunately, there is no API available, yet. I have opened this issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18064) a while ago asking for something very similar, and it is on the Backlog, but no ETA.